# How can I make my cursor appear as a pointer when it's over part of an li element on my page?

Tags: css, html

I have the following HTML:

```
<ul id='x'> 
   <li>
      <a class="document-web1" data-href="/x">x</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a class="document-web2" data-href="/y">y</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I set up this event:

```
$("#content-button-panel")
   .on('click', 'a', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var $link = $(this);
      getContentAjax($link);
   });
```

This works but when my cursor moves over the text it changes
to a vertical text select bar instead of a pointer. Is there
some way that I can make the cursor always appear as an 
arrow when it's over any part of the li element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after read your title its looks like you want

```
li:hover{

cursor:pointer;
}
```

the above will make cursor like

[image]

but after reading your whole question

```
li:hover{

cursor:default;
}
```

and this  will will show cursor like

[image]

<sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

also [**check this**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_cursor&preval=se-resize) its pretty cool with live view

now i would suggest you to write relevant title

Comment: I absolutely agree. :/ But it's more believable to assume he doesn't know property values but can describe the cursor, than that he knows the property values (and doesn't know how to use them in CSS) and have no clue what they look like :) Of course, I might be wrong... o.O

Comment: @Amadan I absolutely agree with you

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to change the cursor you can use this in your CSS:

```
li
{
 cursor: default;
 /*cursor: pointer;*/
}
```

Plus if you’re not really sure which property render which cursor, check the following link it will clear your confusion.

[CSS Cursors](http://www.echoecho.com/csscursors.htm)

Comment: @NullPointer: He says "pointer", but apparently wants an arrow.

Comment: though its little confusing but i have edited my question for both options, he can choose which one he likes and comments out the other one.

Answer (score 0):

The css property you want is `pointer`. setting it to the `default` value will force the browser to render the pointer as an arrow even though there is no `href` attribute on the `a` element.

```
#x a {
    cursor:default;
}
```

Comment: I re-read the question, he wants the arrow instead of the hand. Updated my answer.

Comment: `pointer` is not a CSS property, it's a specific value of `cursor` property.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little new to jquery myself, but I believe you have to use onhover or onmouseover rather than on click.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `cursor` property of `css`, that is `css(cursor, pointer)`, for example